# GitHub Pages + Jekyll + Bootstrap + CDN question

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, cdn

I'm new to GitHub Pages and Jekyll, and moving my blog to it.

I decided to use CDN for Twitter Bootstrap, so just copied example links from official website to the default.html template which is in the `_site/_layouts/default.html`

But when my site is generated, Jekyll creates a local copy of css on the fly, so instead of pointing to the CDN, it creates a link to /assets/styles.css file, but styles are not applied.

Also, at the default.html page bottom, instead of 3 JavaScript files on CDN I got only one unknown to me pointing to CloudFlare.

What I have to do to bypass Jekyll processing links to the files located on CDN?

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: Because javascript links are broken as well and site not displaying correctly because of styles not being applied, or javascript not loaded or both reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the folder structure. I put my whole website in the _site subfolder (you may notice that from the path I provided in the question). The website generated correctly after I moved all of its content to the root folder.